# The name 'input' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I've been C# programming for about a year now and I normally get into problems like this by overlooking a detail somewhere. I feel like I am doing this again but I can't seem to solve the problem. I have a string variable named 'input' I have declared it in an 'if' statement in my 'Main' class like so:
`string input = Console.Readline();`
As a separate 'if' statement, in the same 'Main' class, I have written this:

```
    if (input != null || input != 0)
    {
        //I have code for this part, but it is irrelevant 
    }
    else
    {
        //And this part, but it is also irrelevant
    }
```

my problem is that MonoDevelop is highlighting both of the 'input' variables in the second 'if' statement and saying 'the name input does not exist in the current context'. I feel like I am overlooking something, any help would be appreciated.
My full code is this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
class MainClass
{
    public static string version = "0.0.1";
    public static string precursor = "/:>";

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write ("Console Test ");
        Console.WriteLine (version);
        Console.Write (precursor);
        string start = Console.ReadLine ();

        if (start == "start") {
            while (true) {
                Console.WriteLine ("Started");
                Console.Write (precursor);
                string input = Console.ReadLine ();
            }
        } else {
            Environment.Exit (0);
        }

        if (input != null || input != 0) {
            //Code
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Input null");
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: We need to see them both in situ.  You haven't mentioned if there are different methods, or other structural code that may change the scope of the variables.

Comment: We have *no* clue where you're declaring `input` vs where this code is. Basically, with so little context we can't help you. Have you declared `input` as a local variable in the constructor, for example, and you're then trying to access it in a separate method? Or perhaps it's an instance variable and you're trying to use it in a static method? And if it *is* a string variable, why are you trying to compare it with 0?

Comment: Show the full context please

Comment: please edit your question with the whole content of your code file

Comment: Well. OP does say they declared `input` in another if-statement. So, that'd be the problem. Since `input` is only in scope **inside** that if-statement, it's not going to be usable outside of it. You need to declare it outside and then set it inside.

Comment: Strange, you declare input as string and then compare it with 0.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention to that statement, oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your input variable before your first if statement. Because it is declared inside it is only available inside your if statement (or in this case inside your loop)

Answer (score 1):

`input` exists only in the scope of your `while loop` inside your first `if statement`.

Move it outside.

```
string input = new string();

if (start == "start") {
    while (true) 
    {
            Console.WriteLine ("Started");
            Console.Write (precursor);
            input = Console.ReadLine ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More code is needed, however it may be because you are trying to compare a String to an int. Perhaps you were looking for

```
input.equals("0")?
```

Edit: Looking at your code, you initialized the variable in the if statement. You have to initialize it at the beginning of your function. Even if you just set it to null.

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.Write ("Console Test ");
    Console.WriteLine (version);
    Console.Write (precursor);
    string start = Console.ReadLine ();
    string input = null;

    if (start == "start") {
        while (true) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Started");
            Console.Write (precursor);
            input = Console.ReadLine ();
        }
    } else {
        Environment.Exit (0);
    }

    if (input != null || !input.equals("0")) {
        //Code
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Input null");
    }

}
```

Comment: You would not get that error for comparing a string to an int. You would get an error stating you can't compare a string to an int. ;)

Comment: I would also be careful about saying things like "at the beginning of your function". He just needs to declare it outside of the if-statement, before the variable is used. =)

Comment: Haha yes you are doubly correct, I'll try to be more clear in the future.

Comment: Just trying to be helpful here, since you're answering someone who's new to coding in this language. =)

Answer (score 0):

Your string input is declared inside your loop. Therefor, it isn't known after this loop.
Declare it outside your loop (and initiate it to `null` or `String.Empty`) then fill it inside your loop

Comment: Or inside the first if-statement, even. The loop has little consequence beyond just being a second scope within the first.